# remove old data in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know this question a lot here, But I don`t know about this. This is about chat app.

When message get stored into the firebase database. It would become bigger and bigger as time goes by, I want to delete it. and when should I delete this? I just want to left just only last 10 data. It means if I out the app and again go in, It appears only last 10 sentence and I know about the function limitToFirst and limitToLast (but this is not the delete thing.)

If I pay firebase server, you know, if database's data is large It will be more expensive. but I just want to leave just last 10 sentences at least. 
when they did come back then they can see the last 10sentence and want to delete except for this. how do I do this?

I saw the answer using the date, but I don`t want that. Is that only answer? If I must do that when I get to delete them? When do I invoke the delete function?

I know how to do that almost, but when? If in the app, there are so many friends and I open the chat screen to chat my friend. That time should I delete them using remove function? How am I saving this for server payment?

I don`t want cost a lot. and I want them to be clear, not dirty in my Firebase database console. so want to delete them. Which is the I have to do? Which time is the best time that I should delete them? When open it ? or when close it ? or when users stop the my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in a very simple way. You can use the `getChildrenCount()` method on the node in which you hold the messages to see the exact number of messages. If you are using as an identifier the random key generated by the `push()` method, it's very easy to delete the extra messages. Because the records are by default order by date, you can easily query your database using `limitToLast(limit)` method and than delete the messages like this:

```
yourRef.child("messages").child(messageId).removeValue();
```

Another way to achieve this is to use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and when should I remove them typically?? When users sending the message, that time I have to use getChildrenCount() in my own code?. And so if the count is bigger than 10, then I should delete them? I`m so confused, the timing. Wanna know the typically delete time in chat app...

Comment: I suggest you use that a single time, every time a user starts the app. Not every time a users sends a message. If a user sends in one session more than 10 messages, to display only ten, you can use the `limitToLast(10)` method. If you would delete a message every time a user sends the 11'th message this means more connections that you don't need. You need to delete only once.

Comment: Yah you are definitely helpful to me thanks.You mean when users open the chat app(Activity of chatting, Screen). That time, I should delete once?

Comment: When users open the chat app, not the activity in which they are chatting. The flow, open app -> deleted messages -> open chat activity -> see filtered messages.

Comment: Oh, I see that's because of so many times deleting message is too many connections. So that`s not good, right? Which delete message every time a user sends a message or delete message every time user open the activity. So you suggest me that when user try to open my app and then just check once and delete once is enough?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If there are many messages, it means that are also to many connections, which is no good at all. Yes, check only once and delete unwanted messages.

Comment: Thanks. you are so kind. I appreciate really.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `firebase functions` to delete old data when new ones added to the database that is the best time, you can keep the last 100 messages or less.

Comment: Oh, you told me about the timing, so thank you. and I must use them function to delete them?. And is there any way to delete them automatically? or I just keep checking it using getChildrenCount().

Comment: checking childrencount the best option, or schedule job by using node every period of time

Comment: Is there any way to make schedule job in Firebase like MYSQL?? oh my god, I didn`t know that. what is that?

Comment: using nodejs and firebase functions